# trouble using a scheduled task to run a shell script (ubuntu linux)

Tags: ubuntu, bash, scheduled-tasks, shell-script

I'm trying to create a scheduled task that runs a shell script recurrently, and I'm having some trouble getting it to work. I give it the following command to run every minute:

```
~/Desktop/foo/my_script
```

But it doesn't ever run. (This command runs the shell script through the terminal no problem.) Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Note: Here's my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 15
date >> output.txt
{ time ./foo > /dev/null ; } 2>> output.txt
```

And here's the cron line:

```
* * * * * /home/joe/Desktop/foo/my_script # JOB_ID_3
```

Comment: What scheduler are you using, and how do you know that it doesn't run?

Comment: I'm using the scheduled tasks application from Applications -> System Tools -> Scheduled Tasks in the Ubuntu menu. I know it doesn't run, because the work isn't getting accomplished. I think this application uses cron, because I just ran the command 'crontab -e' and there's an entry for the task I created in scheduled tasks

Comment: ah, please post the cron line. I suspect you've misunderstood (as I did at first) how it works.

Comment: I posted it above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scheduler most likely doesn't know how to expand `~` try giving it an absolute path instead.

EDIT, after solution found:

Another idea I had was that maybe cron was ignoring the line due to all *'s, but I couldn't replicate this. I did find that it's man page is rather unhelpful, but that wikipedia's page on [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is somewhat useful. I was going to suggest using the line:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/joe/Desktop/foo/my_script # JOB_ID_3
```

as this would run at `*/1` (ie every minute that divides by 1) if it continued to fail.

Comment: hmm, just tried this with cron and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: I did, still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Cron runs the tasks in the home directory, so that's where my output file is showing up. This is why I thought it wasn't running.

Comment: That's why it's a good idea to always use absolute paths for files.

Comment: This occurred to me, but I dismissed it as too simple an issue! Though I've fallen foul of this a number of times. The other thing I was going to suggest was that you check that it was +x, but it running correctly in shell suggested that this was also not the issue.